# Get the first string with colon after splitting by whitespace in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string like below.

```
abc : def ghi : jkl
```

I need to split the strings as below.

```
abc :
ghi :
```

I need only the first string with the :. E.g., `abc :` and `ghi :`.

I need to use split method in selenium to identify some values in the screen. 
I am not looking for java method but for a regex pattern to be used inside `split()`.

`split( : ) [0]` This will only gives `abc`. But I need `abc :`

Comment: Selenium is a browser automation library, and does not have any functions that will allow you to manipulate strings. Luckily, whatever language you are using for your Selenium bindings probably has plethora of string processing functions. If you update your question, with what language you are using, and show us your attempts, we would be glad to help you out.

Comment: The question is still missing your attempts. The [tag:selenium] tag is completely irrelevant to this problem. Please have a read through [ask].

Comment: If you are only splitting on `:` then just add a `:` to the output/result

Comment: Is it  always 3 character chunks? What characters are valid in each chunk separated by :

Comment: Not really. Those are examples like Name :  Jason Address : London, UK Date Of Birth : 12/06/1980
I need to capture 
Name :  
 Address : Date of Birth : separately.

Comment: "Date of birth" will be problematic as it contains a space, which you also using as a delmiter. Take fore example "Town : Nob Hill Date Of Birth : 12/06/1980", where does the Town info end and the next label begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after an array of matches, you are better off using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of split:

```js
var data = "abc : def ghi : jkl";
var rx = /\b\w+? :/g;

var arrMatch = data.match(rx);
console.log(arrMatch);
```

See https://regex101.com/r/grhx0W/1/ for a description of the regex.